# Why app.module.ts file is not getting created whenever I create a new angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

Whenever I am creating a new angular app using `ng new "your-app-name"` command, it isn't creating `app.module.ts` file in the project structure and no any prompt is coming in angular cli asking whether to include routing or not. Also, in main.ts file, new app is always being created as bootstrapApplication but I want platformBrowserDynamic. Please suggest a solution.

I tried reinstalling node.js and angular several times and even cross-checked the angular.json configurations but still no luck. I'm using MacBook (M1)

Comment: Welcome gautamayush12, by default angular creates a standalone app, if you want to create at older way, use the follow flag, --standalone=false.
ng new MyAppName --standalone=false

Answer (score 10):

By default Angular 17 creates a standalone app.

This is the whole list of options can be pass when creates an angular app [Angular #options](https://angular.io/cli/new#options).

If you want to generate a new app without this feature use the next command:

```bash
ng new NoStandaloneApp --standalone=false
```

This will create the app.module.ts file and at main.ts will use the platformBrowserDynamic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Joel. I had one query btw, do I need to add this property --standalone=false at the end every-time whenever I create a new app. Can you please clarify.

Comment: Hi @gautamayush12 only if you are using *@angular/cli equal or higher than 17*, yes you should use --standalone=false only for the propouse to create the old way using modules arquitecture. Nowadays standalone give the performace per each component/route like using modules.

Answer (score 3):

This is related to the new version of Angular,
run command `ng new --no-standalone AppName` to create web application.